# PHP Cloneable Object

Tags: php, object, clone

I went through this example on the PHP Manual.

```
<?php
class SubObject
{
    static $instances = 0;
    public $instance;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->instance = ++self::$instances;
    }

    public function __clone() {
        $this->instance = ++self::$instances;
    }
}

class MyCloneable
{
    public $object1;
    public $object2;

    function __clone()
    {
        // Force a copy of this->object, otherwise
        // it will point to same object.
        $this->object1 = clone $this->object1;
        $this->object2 = clone $this->object2;
    }
}

$obj = new MyCloneable();

$obj->object1 = new SubObject();
$obj->object2 = new SubObject();

$obj2 = clone $obj;


print("Original Object:\n");
print_r($obj);

print("Cloned Object:\n");
print_r($obj2);

?>
```

When i execute this `$obj2 = clone $obj;` can someone explain me what happens actually ? Will this call `MyCloneable` Class's  `function __clone()` or `SubObject` Class's `public function __clone()` ?

Step by step explanation would be more helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__clone` function handles the `clone` keyword. Using

```
$obj2 = clone $obj;
```

could be represented as

```
$obj2 = $obj::__clone();
```

But that's obvious to you.

`clone ...` calls the `__clone` method of the `MyCloneable` class. It has nothing to do with the `SubObject` class. `object1` and `object2` are only properties of the `$obj` object which is of class `MyCloneable`.

Of course, when you call the `clone`, the `object1` and `object2` properties will be cloned but they'll still be the object's properties. The `$obj2` will be of class `MyCloneable`.

Does my answer satisfy your needs?

### EDIT:

`clone` keywords inside the `MyCloneable::__clone()` method are creating clones of the `$object1` and `$object2` properties. In practice, it gives nothing because you're assigning the clones to the *makers* of these clones.
What happens in `MyCloneable::__clone()` - it is calling `SubObject::__clone()` method which in fact does this:

```
$this->instance = ++self::$instances;
```

Notice that `instances` property is *static* so every time you create a **new** or **clone** an existing object, the `instances` increments.

Comment: Thanks for answering. When you said `clone ... calls the __clone method of the MyCloneable class.` There is another `clone` keyword in the `__clone()` of the `MyCloneable` class. What happens there actually?